# SQL Server Conversion Types

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I have the following SELECT in SQL Server:

```
SELECT  
    th.CidadeCod,
    th.ContratoCod,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), ( SUM(th.PlacasLidas)/SUM(th.Trafego) ) * 100) AS [IndiceOCR]
FROM 
    controle.TrafegoFaixaHora th 
INNER JOIN ssis.Contratos c ON th.ContratoCod = c.ContratoCod AND th.CidadeCod = c.CidadeCod
INNER JOIN controle.Equipamentos e ON th.ContratoCod = e.ContratoCod AND th.CidadeCod = e.CidadeCod
WHERE 
    c.FlagAtivo = 1 AND e.FlagOcr = 1
GROUP BY 
    th.CidadeCod,
    th.ContratoCod
```

But the error is returned:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

What should I do ?

Comment: what are the datatypes of `th.PlacasLidas` and `th.Trafego`?

Comment: If you remove the CONVERT statement, what value get's returned?  I think perhaps the size of the decimal you are converting too is too small for your result perhaps?

Comment: break this column, "CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), ( SUM(th.PlacasLidas)/SUM(th.Trafego) ) * 100)" & try for which operation it is showing error. Break & debug...

Comment: Since the error is about converting to int I suspect that both PlacesLidas and Trafego are of type int. So you have 2 problems. The first problem that the outcome of your calculation will be an int with the decimal part cut of (not rounded !) and the second problem is that it does not fit in you decimal(5,2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  
    th.CidadeCod,
    th.ContratoCod,
    ( SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),th.PlacasLidas))/SUM(th.Trafego) ) * 100 AS [IndiceOCR]
FROM 
    controle.TrafegoFaixaHora th 
INNER JOIN ssis.Contratos c ON th.ContratoCod = c.ContratoCod AND th.CidadeCod = c.CidadeCod
INNER JOIN controle.Equipamentos e ON th.ContratoCod = e.ContratoCod AND th.CidadeCod = e.CidadeCod
WHERE 
    c.FlagAtivo = 1 AND e.FlagOcr = 1
GROUP BY 
    th.CidadeCod,
    th.ContratoCod
```

This error occour because your number is bigger than five digits.

I believe that when you divide two int you need convert one before operation.